# Sending multiple cells to the last line of another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I've built this code using a bunch of other codes that I've pieced together, not being very good at VBA myself.

I have one workbook that is mine, it containing data that is all over the place, eg: name is L2, account number is C3 etc etc.

This code is to send all of this data in a specific line, to another work book that is used by the rest of my colleagues, and to the very last line of that workbook.

```
 Sub Save_To_Register()

 Dim count As Integer
 Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range,

'Officer Name
Set r1 = Range("L2")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A100")
r2.Value = r1.Value

'Account Number
Set r1 = Range("C3")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C100")
r2.Value = r1.Value

'Account Address
Set r1 = Range("C4")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D100")
r2.Value = r1.Value

'Applicant of Take Over
Set r1 = Range("L3")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E100")
r2.Value = r1.Value

'Applicant of Take Over
Set r1 = Range("C3")
Set r2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C100")
r2.Value = r1.Value

Application.Workbooks("PM-#8873088-v4-SUB-METERING_REGISTER.XLS").Activate
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A100:K100").Copy

ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select


count = 1

Do While Not (ActiveCell.Value = None)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:K1").Select
    count = count + 1

Loop

ActiveSheet.Range("A" & count).PasteSpecial 


End Sub
```

This isn't a very efficient code, i'm basically mirroring the cells L2, C3, C4 & L3 to a single row A100:K100. Included in that line are a bunch of =Today() formulas.

Everything was working fine, though not as efficiently as it could be. When i use this VBA, it copies all data to the other workbook perfectly **but it updates all the dates from previous entries**.

I thought that using pastespecial would transfer over the values only, but it seems that all the date cells that were copied over into the new workbook (Sub metering register) are =Today(), rather than just being the actual value.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to make sure that the date values are copied over as values rather than as their formula, or how to stop the values from updating each day in the new workbook?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need `xlPasteValues` after you pastespecial.

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("A" & count).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

**Edit:**
To critics of this answer: I realize my post doesn't encourage a more efficient approach that doesn't involve copy/paste -- but when a man (or woman) is only **one word** away from a solution... I just post it and don't ask questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cells(row, column).Value` syntax.

Few more tips, about efficiency. Try activating and selecting obejcts as least as possible. In your code it's enough to open the additional workbook, store references to workbook in 2 reference variables of type `Workbook`, for example:

```
Dim myWorkbook As Workbook
Set myWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
```

Then you could make use of this syntax `myWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value` (just example). Then, in code, you can use `With` block, when you don't want to type all workbook names.